# Westworld: Is the "biology" of the Hosts ever explained?

Tags: biology, westworld-2016

I became less familiar with the show after season 2. I believe one character reflects on the way the Hosts used to be and the audience is shown a sort of steampunk version of the robots with actual gears. Eventually the Host bodies are built by sort of accretion from some plastic-like substance although I believe they have human organs -- once fully formed they are not plastic throughout, I think because they not only bleed but the technicians have to worry about infections while repairing the Hosts. They even have apparently human brains although a key component of the that brain appears to be a small, marble-like sphere which contains memories(?) and/or "souls" of the Hosts which can be re-implanted in new bodies. Is this gone into and if so, which episodes go into this?

EDIT: A specific question is, do the organs form in the plastic body we see or are they added in a separate process? Is this shown?